# How Custom Translator handles the inlines in TMX

Tags: microsoft-translator

Should I care about the markup content elements (`<bpt>`, `<ept>`, `<it>`, and `<ph>`) when uploading TMX for training?

Should we clean up those (e.g. by removing `bpt-ept` pairs, or replacing `ph` with actual values?